# How to convert model to arrays in iOS swift3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

from the below code, How can I take two different arrays of movie and genre. Then I need to use that models with these two arrays?Could anyone guide me to do this task.

```
models = [
        Model(movie:"The Dark Night", genre:"Action"),
        Model(movie:"The Avengers", genre:"Action"),
        Model(movie:"Logan", genre:"Action"),
        Model(movie:"Shutter Island", genre:"Thriller"),
        Model(movie:"Inception", genre:"Thriller"),
        Model(movie:"Titanic", genre:"Romance"),
        Model(movie:"La la Land", genre:"Romance"),
        Model(movie:"Gone with the Wind", genre:"Romance"),
        Model(movie:"Godfather", genre:"Drama"),
        Model(movie:"Moonlight", genre:"Drama")
    ]
```

Comment: `SearchName` and `nameArr` are string array? I think you only filter name. You need to filter your entire contact object.

Comment: @Kuldeep : Yes, okay but How?

Comment: Like this : `arrFilteredContact = YOUR_CONTACT_ARRAY.filter{$0.name.localizedLowercase.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)} `

Comment: This question has been so much edited that it's unclear now what you want.

Comment: @Larme: I have two separate arrays like movie and genre. I need to use that arrays to models array. I can not split like movie and genre like that

Comment: @ios6457468234 From the above models array. Do you want to generate two diff arrays movies and genres ??

Comment: What is the purpose of splitting the model into two arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to figure out the purpose of the segregating `movie` and `genre` in separate `array`. However this can be done as follows :

```
var movies = [String]()
var genres = [String]()
for model in models {
    movies.append(model.movie)
    genres.append(model.genre)
}
```

And in more swifty way :

```
var movies = models.map{$0.movie}
var genres = models.map{$0.genre}
```

Instead of segregating them, it can be used as `model.movie` and `model.genre` anywhere.